# Altium Designer 16 - CurrentDate Special String Format

Tags: schematics, altium, documentation

In previous projects, I used the `CurrentDate` special string, in the format *YYYY-MM-DD* (see the image below).

[image]

Opening the same project on a different installation of Altium, the format has been automatically changed to MM/DD/YYYY. Is there a way to change this format?

I'm unsure if I changed it in the past. If I did, I don't remember where this setting lives, and I can't seem to find it in the Altium documentation. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Just a wild guess, it uses the format you have set in your Windows Regional Settings

Comment: That was the trick! Thank you. Feel free to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It most likely uses your Regional Setting from Windows.